# copy Excel sheet to Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, copy, paste, vba

I need to export the sheet 'GreatIdea' to a Word document. 'GreatIdea' is divided into pages and my columns are based on these pages.

**A - C contain a table of contents, D - F contain chapter 1, ...**

```
Sub test()

' Open LOL.docx'
Dim appWD As Word.Application
Set appWD = New Word.Application
Dim docWD As Word.Document
Set docWD = appWD.Documents.Open("C:\Users\TOM\Desktop\LOL.docx")
docWD.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

' Copy from GreatIdea to LOL.docx'

Range("A1:K40").Copy
appWD.Selection.PasteSpecial

appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "OEF_OFFERTE"
appWD.ActiveDocument.Close
appWD.Quit
Set appWD = Nothing
Set docWD = Nothing

End Sub
```

This copies everything into Word, but doesn't copy the column layout. Other solutions to copy everything are accepted too. I just need to make sure all the data from every column gets copied.

#### Mike's answer edited:

```
 Range("A1:C40").Copy
 appWD.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=True
```

Comment: Why do you use `"double quotes"` to denotate your comments? The correct syntax in VBA is with a single quote, `'Like this.`

Comment: I know, but in Stackoverflow it messes up the colors?

Comment: I edited my question to double single quotes, seems to do the trick too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are in a WORD application (AppWD), there's a better function:

```
expression.PasteExcelTable(LinkedToExcel, WordFormatting, RTF)
```

Try one of these

```
AppWD.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, True   ' aequivalent to PasteSpecial As RTF
AppWD.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, True  ' keeps Excel formats
AppWD.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False ' aequivalent to PasteSpecial As HTML
```

Good luck - MikeD

Comment: Edit: Got it, check my initial question.