# larger text than cell width

Tags: excel, layout, ms-word, vba

I'm [copying a piece of text from Excel to Word using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5537362):

```
Range("A1:C37").Copy
appWD.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=True
```

The trouble is some cells contain text which is longer than the cell width. In Excel when I align right the text just continues into the other column. Trouble is, when copied into Word it automatically wraps text together. Is there a way of turning this off or a way around this so my text stays on the same line?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Where would the extra text go?! What yould you like to happen?

Comment: across, like it does in Excel?

Comment: "across" to where? "Under" the neighbouring cell like in Excel? This isn't an option in Word.

Comment: Yes, like a merge would do. But when I do this it puts the text in 1 column ... It does do it from Left to Right, but from Right to Left it wraps my text.

Comment: Yes a sort of merging. But it automatically continues into the other column when it's aligned Left. When it's aligned Right it wraps itself.

Comment: well - the text does not "continue to other columns". When you type something into the neighboring cell, the *display* of your long one is just truncated. This is a behaviour you can transfer to WORD only if you paste the Excel source as *Excel Object*. In all other cases your text will be WORDified and starts to break, wrap and resize like in a grown up text processor (eyyy it IS a text processor after all ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to merge cells. You may or may not know this already, but merging is done like this:

```
Selection.Cells.Merge
```

Warning: merged cells can be a pain to format afterwards, especially if you want to insert or remove columns.

Comment: Well wasn't really what I needed, but thanks for the info. I just edited my columns, so the columns that need to align right are large enough, because the other columns automatically merge into other cells.